# Analyzing ranking data

Tags: ranking

I'm trying to analyzing ranking data, a simple data set would be:

[image]

I looked at some existing examples, one is survey monkey:

[image]

.. but their equation is not clear, so just wondering whats the best way to do this when the options have a min and max required?